# Reported speech confusion

Tags: past-perfect, reported-speech, backshifting

#### Direct speech

1. “I worked in a bank for 3 years,” said Michael.

#### Reported speech

2. Michael said that he **had** worked in a bank for three years.

Is *had worked* necessary there, or would just *worked* have been ok when converting (1) to reported speech in (2)

I know that standard practice is to go one step back in the past. Is doing so *always* necessary?

Answer (score 2):

> Michael said that he worked in a bank for three years.

This sentence is fine and accurately reports what Michael said, but it does introduce some ambiguity. Was Michael saying that he **has** worked in a bank for the past three years (and still works there) or that he worked in a bank for three years in the past (and is no longer working there)?

> Michael said that he *has worked* in a bank for three years.

With no doubt or ambiguity, this statement would correspond to: "I *have worked* in a bank for three years," said Michael.

Therefore, in order to clearly communicate Michael's intent when he says, "I worked in a bank for three years" (simple past), we need the past perfect:

> Michael said that he **had worked** in a bank for three years.